# C++ - QT Framework / Cannot evoke method

Tags: c++, qt, file, download, qt5

everyone. First I want to apologize for my bad English. Here is the code of one of my personal project and I need help. The current code at execution should download this video - http://media09.vbox7.com/s/21/21bbc2dca3r3634e3389.mp4, but does not work. The video is downloaded only when the following code be placed in

// main.cpp

```
int main (int argc, char * argv [])
{
    QApplication a (argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show ();

    QtDownload dl;
    dl.setTarget ( "http://media09.vbox7.com/s/21/21bbc2dca3r3634e3389.mp4");
    dl.download ();
      // Quit when the download is done.
    // QObject :: connect (& dl, SIGNAL (done ()), & app, SLOT (quit ()));
    return a.exec ();
}
```

and I want to run in the method MainWindow - example:
// mainwindow.cpp

```
MainWindow :: MainWindow (QWidget * parent):
    QMainWindow (parent),
    ui (new Ui :: MainWindow)
{

    QtDownload dl;
    dl.setTarget ( "http://media09.vbox7.com/s/21/21bbc2dca3r3634e3389.mp4");
    dl.download ();
     // Quit when the download is done.
    // QObject :: connect (& dl, SIGNAL (done ()), & app, SLOT (quit ()));
........
}
```

Here is the current code of the program.

// downloader.pro

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2017-01-12T15:22:17
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui
QT += network
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = downloader
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

// mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QObject>
#include <QString>
#include <QtNetwork/QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QtNetwork/QNetworkReply>
namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};


class QtDownload : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit QtDownload();
    QNetworkAccessManager manager;
    QString target;

    void setTarget(const QString& t);

private:


signals:
    void done();

public slots:
    void download();
    void downloadFinished(QNetworkReply* data);
    void downloadProgress(qint64 recieved, qint64 total);
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

//main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtCore>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

// mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QUrl>
#include <QtNetwork/QNetworkRequest>
#include <QFile>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QtNetwork/QNetworkReply>
#include <QtNetwork/QNetworkReply>
#include <QByteArray>
#include <QObject>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{


    ui->setupUi(this);


    //  QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);
    QtDownload dl;

    dl.setTarget("http://media09.vbox7.com/s/21/21bbc2dca3r3634e3389.mp4");
    dl.download();
      //quit when the download is done.
    //  QObject::connect(&dl, SIGNAL(done()), &app, SLOT(quit()));

}


MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}


QtDownload::QtDownload() : QObject(0) {
    QObject::connect(&manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),this, SLOT(downloadFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
}




void QtDownload::setTarget(const QString &t) {
    this->target = t;
}

void QtDownload::downloadFinished(QNetworkReply *data) {
    QFile localFile("C:/downloadedfile.mp4");
    if (!localFile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly))
        return;
    const QByteArray sdata = data->readAll();
    localFile.write(sdata);
    qDebug() << sdata;
    localFile.close();

    emit done();
}

void QtDownload::download() {
    QUrl url = QUrl::fromEncoded(this->target.toLocal8Bit());
    QNetworkRequest request(url);
    QObject::connect(manager.get(request), SIGNAL(downloadProgress(qint64,qint64)), this, SLOT(downloadProgress(qint64,qint64)));

}

void QtDownload::downloadProgress(qint64 recieved, qint64 total) {
    qDebug() << recieved << total;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried your code, I had the same problem that you report, only change the creation of the object to a pointer and magically arranged, I still do not understand the reason for error, I will continue to search for reason.

You must be:

```
...
ui->setupUi(this);
QtDownload *dl =  new QtDownload();
dl->setTarget( "http://media09.vbox7.com/s/21/21bbc2dca3r3634e3389.mp4");
dl->download();
...
```

Comment: Ok thanks for your help. Another problem is i dont have access to progressBar in GUI                                                                     void QtDownload::downloadProgress(qint64 recieved, qint64 total) {
  //  qDebug() << recieved << total;                                                                                              MainWindow::ui->progressBar->setMaximum(total); // doesn't works
MainWindow::ui->progressBar->setValue(recieved);  //// doesn't works
} How i access to progressBar(Ui_MainWindow class) in QtDownload class ?

Comment: @Howto complete code: https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/downloader

Answer (score -1):

So.. if you want to run the download at `QMainWindow`the object `QtDownload dl` should be a pointer property of `MainWindow` or it will not be destroyed (unless `dl`, as a `QObject, has`MainWindow` as parent).

Run it into `main()` function does not work in this case because the application will run when `exec()` was called, so the download

So it will be something like this:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    // Delete the `dl` object
    ~MainWindow() { delete dl; }

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QtDownload *dl; // Declare it here
};

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow),
    dl(nullptr)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    //  QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);
    dl = new QtDownload();
    dl->setTarget("http://media09.vbox7.com/s/21/21bbc2dca3r3634e3389.mp4");
    dl->download();

    // connect the signal `done()` to save the file or anything like that
    QObject::connect(dl, SIGNAL(done()), this, SLOT(downloadFinished()));

}
```

Comment: **You should connect the signal done() to QMainWindow::close()**, why??

Comment: When your work is done, the window will be close and the QApplication as well because no other window will remains visible.

Comment: In which part of the question does that require?